# What's the equivalent for setting an "identity transform" in 2D space?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

For 3D space, I use:

```
self.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
```

what corresponds here if I just need 2d space and want to assign the identity transform? I knew there was something, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567829/catransform3d-vs-cgaffinetransform) for **a good explanation of CATransform3D and CGAffinetransform** (the one you need).